# Find roots of a complex function in python

Tags: python, function, complex-numbers

I have a complex function for which I'm trying to find the roots. Have tried using the newton method but it didn't converge because when the x changes by even a small amount, the function changes quite a lot. I also tried splitting my function in a real and imaginary parts and tried using ''fsolve'' and ''root''. I managed to find roots of both parts but those weren't roots of the original function. My function is:

```
def f1(x):
    f1=np.e**(complex(0,-2*x*sqrtep*(a+b)))
    g1=np.e**(complex(0,-2*x*sqrtes*(a-b)))
    return bita*gamma*f1*g1-1+((bita-gamma)/((bita*gamma)-1))*(gamma*g1-bita*f1)
```

where I set the parameters bita,gamma,a and b to any value I choose (currently have 11,5,1 and -0.5 respectively)

I copy pasted the equation in WolframAlpha and the solutions came up. That leads me to think there is a way to find them with python but I can't seem to figure out how. I checked many stackoverflow questions but none of them worked for me.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: You can try solving for the norm of the function to get both real and imaginary parts at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't used norm before so I'll have a look at it and let you know if it worked.

Comment: Let me know if it works (it should, you can even just minimize the function instead of finding roots, so more algorithms), I'll turn it into an answer.

Comment: What I tried to do was return `np.linalg.norm` of my function and then find the solutions using the root method. What I get however is the error **f1=np.e**(complex(0,-2*x*sqrtep*(a+b)))

TypeError: can't convert complex to float** and I don't see where there the problem is. Is that what you what you were thinking of using? Also not sure what's the difference between abs and norm.

Comment: abs is the square root of the norm. Are you using fsolve? or minimize? Could be interesting to have a full reproducer, as I can't test this myself.

Comment: Tried fsolve and I'll give minimize a try as well, although I feel like I'm going to get the same error. Why can't you test it out by the way? The function is all you need and I've given the variables I used below the function.

Comment: forgot to include 2 of them actually. This is what I used: `sqrtes=np.sqrt(2.25)
sqrtep=np.sqrt(1.44)
bita=(sqrtep+1)/(sqrtep-1)
gamma=(sqrtes+1)/(sqrtes-1)
a=1
b=-a/2`

Comment: Still haven't made any progress. I tried solving it with something simpler such as `def f(x):
    return np.linalg.norm(np.e**(complex(0,x))-1)`   .Whether I use the np.linalg.norm or not I get the error  **TypeError: can't convert complex to float** with both fsolve and minimise.

Comment: Let me have a look at it tomorrow.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I wrote the [cxroots](https://rparini.github.io/cxroots/) library to solve this kind of problem. You'd just need to specify a region in which to find all the roots. For your specific problem, this will find all the roots in the square `[-5,5]x[-5,5]` in the complex plane without any modification to the `f1` function in your question:

```
>>> from cxroots import Rectangle
>>> result = Rectangle([-5,5], [-5,5]).roots(f1)
>>> print(result)
 Multiplicity |               Root
------------------------------------------------
      1       | -4.340896457472 -0.651119887677i
      1       | -3.220603959478 -0.759700918366i
      1       | -2.264676209361 -0.788422494489i
      1       | -1.187713596076 -0.670625381177i
      1       |  0.000000000000 -0.626958322503i
      1       |  1.187713596076 -0.670625381177i
      1       |  2.264676209361 -0.788422494489i
      1       |  3.220603959478 -0.759700918366i
      1       |  4.340896457472 -0.651119887677i
```

You can also plot the roots with

```
>>> result.show()
```

[Plot showing roots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRi6a.png)

and get the roots and multiplicies as regular lists with

```
>>> roots, multiplicities = result
>>> print(roots)
[(4.340896457472305-0.651119887676796j), (1.1877135960758887-0.6706253811768764j), (3.2206039594776636-0.7597009183662711j), (2.2646762093614563-0.7884224944890115j), (-1.1877135960758887-0.6706253811768764j), (5.576755891018317e-27-0.6269583225027183j), (-4.340896457472305-0.651119887676796j), (-2.2646762093614563-0.7884224944890115j), (-3.2206039594776636-0.7597009183662711j)]
```

Running `pip install cxroots[plot]` will install the library and the dependencies needed to make the above plot. Note that the rootfinding is quicker and potentially more accurate if you also provide the derivative of your function but it's not generally necessary, the library will approximate it numerically if it's not given. Also, in general, the function must be analytic in the specified region, though that's no issue for your example.

Comment: Hi,
I’m using cxroots to find all the roots of a complex function f(z). When I choose a rectangle of size real(-5000,5000), imag(-5000,5000), it gives me 14 roots, each with multiplicity 1. The roots are symmetric about the imaginary axis. That is it has 7 roots of the form x+iy and other 7 roots of the form -x+iy. 
So, when I choose a rectangle of size real(0,5000), imag(-5000,5000), it gives me only 5 roots (two roots with a multiplicity of 2). Which implies, it did not detect two roots compared to the former case. Why is this happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I have replied to you on the issue you made: https://github.com/rparini/cxroots/issues/299

Answer (score 0):

I tried several `scipy.optimize` methods and none of them worked for complex exponentials. What worked for me was `mpmath import findroot` although for it to work I had to change `e**(complex(0,-2*x*sqrtep*(a+b)))` into `e**(-2j*x*sqrtep*(a+b))`.